# How to print values at points with Google Chart API?

Tags: charts

I have gone through their developer guide but haven't been able to find a way to print the value at points (in case of line charts) or after bars (bar charts).Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with a label, it's [in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#Labels) - it has an example with a bar chart.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's not possible at the moment. I looked at the Google Chart API myself few days ago. Instead I found (and probably will use) FusionCharts Free pacakge.

It has the features you need, plus those points can be interactive.

Comment: Although Kristian is right, thanks for suggesting FusinCharts, it is looking better than Google Chart API. Will try it out.